# Trigger Delete doesn't update my attribute

Tags: trigger, delete

Hi I try to update my custom attribute "newKundenwert" after deleting e certain record. The deletion itself works but the attribute remain the same value.

Could you help me please?

```
trigger UpdateKundenwertDeleteAbo on Abo__c (before delete) {

String accIdErsterSchritt;
Integer anzahlAbos = 0;
Schema.Account newKundenwert; 

//Betroffenen Account selektieren

for(Abo__c c : System.trigger.old){
    accIdErsterSchritt = [Select accountname__c From Abo__c where Id =:c.Id LIMIT 1].accountname__c;         
}

//Anzahl Abos zu den Account raussuchen
anzahlAbos = database.countQuery('Select COUNT() From Abo__c where accountname__c = :accIdErsterSchritt');


//Update Kundenwert
newKundenwert = [Select Id From Account where Account.Id =: accIdErsterSchritt];
newKundenwert.Kundenwert__c = anzahlAbos;
update newKundenwert;
```

}

Comment: did you check what's coming out of the countQuery?

Comment: The old value before I delete something.

Comment: this trigger is not bulkified and will fail when mass delete is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do 
 accIdErsterSchritt =c.accountname__c; ?

Put debug statements to check for account fetched.

Comment: The "accIdErsterSchritt " fetches but the "anzahlAbos " remains the old value.

Comment: that is because the object was not deleted so your count will be the same. You will have to do after delte

Comment: Hi I found the answer 

trigger UpdateKundenwertDeleteAbo on Abo__c (after delete) {
 
    Integer anzahlAbos = 0;
    Schema.Account newKundenwert; 
    
    //Account initialisieren    
    Abo__c account = System.trigger.old.get(0);
    
    //Neue Anzahl an Abos ermitteln
    anzahlAbos = [Select COUNT() From Abo__c where accountname__c =:account.accountname__c];   
    
    //Update Kundenwert
    newKundenwert = [Select Id From Account where Account.Id =: account.accountname__c];
    newKundenwert.Kundenwert__c = anzahlAbos;
    update newKundenwert;
}

Comment: Yep, you may want to bulkify as suggested above and mark as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are doing the update the account before delete the record, and you are counting the deleted record.

I would move your logic to the after delete:

```
trigger UpdateKundenwertDeleteAbo on Abo__c (after delete) {

Set<String> accountNamesToRecalculate = new Set<String>();
for(Abo__c c : System.trigger.old){
  accountNamesToRecalculate.add(c.accountname__c);

}

Account[] accountsToUpdate = new Account[]{};
for(AggregateResult result : [select count(id) total, accountname__c from Abo__c where accountname__c in:accountNamesToRecalculate]){
  accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
    Id = (String) result.get('accountname__c')
    ,Kundenwert__c = (Decimal) result.get('total');
  ));
}

update accountsToUpdate;
```